# make my cpp application to not open a cmd prompt if I click the exe

Tags: c++, c, netbeans, mingw

I have a simple c++ application which is developed in windows environment with "mingw" and Netbeans. When I click the "exe" a command prompt appears with my application window. I dont want this "command prompt window". How can I restrict this window and open only my application window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the mingw FAQ (http://www.mingw.org/wiki/FAQ):

> How do I remove DOS command windows?
>
> In the link step add a "-mwindows" switch to the command line.

Answer (score 3):

Windows applications can use either `CONSOLE` subsystem or `WINDOWS` subsystem.

`WINDOWS` subsystem is for GUI applications. It requires that you have `WinMain()` as entry point. In MinGW, you can enable Windows subsystem using `-mwindows` compiler command line parameter.

`CONSOLE` subsystem is for command line console applications. It requires that you have `main()` (or `wmain()`) as entry point. However, you can quickly release console by calling `FreeConsole()`. Your app will still shortly flash, but app will appear to not have any console, and you can actually create normal windows and widgets. This can be used to create dual-mode applications which can operate either in command-line or GUI mode.

Comment: -1 " It requires that you have WinMain() as entry point" is incorrect.